# jest test css for positioning

Tags: css, testing, jestjs

anyone know how to write a jest test for this?

```
loginBtn.onclick = (()=>{
  loginForm.style.marginLeft = "0%";
  loginText.style.marginLeft = "0%";
});
```

i've already tried this but it didnt work

```
beforeEach(() => {
        document.documentElement.innerHTML = html.toString();
    });

test('clicking signup moves the styles', () => {
        const loginForm = document.querySelector("form.login");
        const loginText = document.querySelector(".title-text .login");
        expect(loginForm.style.marginLeft).toBeFalsy();
        expect(loginText.style.marginLeft).toBeFalsy();
```

Answer (score 0):

.toBeFalsy() will not be true because '0%' is a string different than 0 which is falsy

You will have to use `toEqual('0%')` for this situation

```
expect(loginForm.style.marginLeft).toEqual('0%');
expect(loginText.style.marginLeft).toEqual('0%');
```